# Display only one name for there respective details

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [spid] => 21
        [name] => Gaurav
        [partner_acc_name] => SkyTechMasters

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [spid] => 21
        [name] => Gaurav
        [partner_acc_name] => TestPartner

    )


    This is the array i have show above.
```

[image]

i want that the "Gaurav" name should be display one for the "Partner_acc_name".

Code-

```
<tr class="all_partner" for="<?php echo $get_partner_forecast_val['spid']; ?>">

                                    <td for="<?php echo $get_partner_forecast_val['spid']; ?>"rowspan="<?php echo ($product_no*2)+2; ?>"><?php echo $get_partner_forecast_val['name'];?></td>

                                    <td for="<?php echo $get_partner_forecast_val['spid']; ?>"rowspan="<?php echo ($product_no*2)+2; ?>"><?php echo $get_partner_forecast_val['partner_acc_name'];?></td>

                                    <td for="<?php echo $get_partner_forecast_val['spid']; ?>"  rowspan="<?php echo ($product_no*2)+2; ?>"><?php echo $get_partner_forecast_val['crm_acc_name'];?></td>
```

This is the code.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: see the code i updated

Comment: You need some `rowspan`...

Comment: ok.but the gaurav name should be display once only for there respective next column name

Comment: But how sure you are that the partner_acc_name will be occuring everytime when name will be Gaurav. That can rpeat after 10 elements also.

Comment: no the partner name always coming but if the name of the partner_acc_name is same then it will display only once.

Answer (score 0):

well i solve this answer now with the help of Jquery.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$temp = array();
    foreach($partner_forecast as $get_partner_forecast_val) {
?>
<tr class="all_partner" for="<?php echo $get_partner_forecast_val['spid']; ?>">

<td for="<?php echo $get_partner_forecast_val['spid']; ?>" rowspan="<?php echo ($product_no*2)+2; ?>">
    <?php if(!in_array($get_partner_forecast_val['name'], $temp)) echo $get_partner_forecast_val['name'];?>
</td>
<td for="<?php echo $get_partner_forecast_val['spid']; ?>" rowspan="<?php echo ($product_no*2)+2; ?>">
    <?php echo $get_partner_forecast_val['partner_acc_name'];?>
</td>
<td for="<?php echo $get_partner_forecast_val['spid']; ?>" rowspan="<?php echo ($product_no*2)+2; ?>">
    <?php echo $get_partner_forecast_val['crm_acc_name'];?>
</td>

</tr>
<?php
        if(!in_array($get_partner_forecast_val['name'], $temp))
            temp[] = $get_partner_forecast_val['name']; // add name to array which has been displayed so that we can check in next record whether its nedd to diaply or not
    }
?>
```